# Drawing a Circle with Class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program where I have to draw three circle shapes from a class(data structure) that will output in the console.

The problem I'm having with my program is that my code compiles, however, the output goes crazy and doesn't draw the circles.

I'm still new to C++ and if anyone can help me out on how to fix this, I would appreciate it.

My Current Code:

```
////// Circle.h
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Circle
{
private:
    char type;
    int serialNumber = 0;
    double radius = 0.0;
    double density = 0.0;

public:
    Circle(char, int, double);
    Circle(char, int, double, double);
    ~Circle();

    void setType(char);
    void setSerialNumber(int);
    void setRadius(double);
    void setDensity(double);

    char getType() const;
    int getSerialNumber() const;
    double getRadius() const;
    double getDensity() const;
};

////// Circle.cpp
// #include "Circle.h"

    Circle::Circle(char c, int s, double r)
    {
        type = c;
        serialNumber = s;
        radius = r;
    }

    Circle::Circle(char c, int s, double r, double d)
    {
        type = c;
        serialNumber = s;
        radius = r;
        density = d;
    }

    Circle::~Circle()
    {
        cout << "Shapes deleted!" << endl;
    }

    void Circle::setType(char c)
    {
        if(c == 'S' || c == 'C')
            type = c;
    }

    void Circle::setSerialNumber(int s)
    {
        if(s > 0)
            serialNumber = s;
    }

    void Circle::setRadius(double r)
    {
        if(r > 0)
            radius = r;
    }

    void Circle::setDensity(double d)
    {
        if(d > 0)
            density = d;
    }

    char Circle::getType() const
    {
        return type;
    }

    int Circle::getSerialNumber() const
    {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    double Circle::getRadius() const
    {
        return radius;
    }

    double Circle::getDensity() const
    {
        return density;
    }

////// main.cpp
// #include "Circle.h"

void drawAll(Circle *[], int);
void drawType(Circle *);
void drawCircle(Circle *);
void drawSpray(Circle *);
void deleteAll(Circle *[], int);

/// For 'C' type the system should display a circle.
/// For 'S' type the system displays a spray pattern just like those used in Microsoft Paint.

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int SIZE = 3;
    Circle * arrCircle[SIZE] = {nullptr};

    arrCircle[0] = new Circle('C', 1001, 20);

    /// Create a Circle whose serial number is 1001 and the radius is 20.

    /// Type 'C' indicates Circle type.

    arrCircle[1] = new Circle('S', 1002, 25, 30);

    /// Create a Spray whose serial number is 1002, the radius is 25, and the density is 30%.

    /// Type 'S' indicates Spray type.

    arrCircle[2] = new Circle('S', 1003, 40, 80);

    /// Create a Spray whose serial number is 1003, the radius is 40, and the density is 80%.

    drawAll(arrCircle, SIZE);

    /// Draw all shapes. The function uses a for loop to display the circles and sprays in arrCircle.

    deleteAll(arrCircle, SIZE);

    /// Delete all shapes.

    return 0;
}

void drawAll(Circle *arr[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        if(arr[i] != nullptr)
        {
            cout << "Circle #" << arr[i]->getSerialNumber() << endl;
            drawType(arr[i]);
        }
}

void drawType(Circle *p)
{
    if(p->getType() == 'C')
        drawCircle(p);

    else if(p->getType() == 'S')
        drawSpray(p);
}

void drawCircle(Circle *p)
{
    double r = p->getRadius();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int rto = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 40; i++)
        {
            x = abs(i - 20);
            y = abs(j - 20);
            r = pow(pow(x, rto) + pow(y, rto), 0.5);

            if(19.5 < r && r < 20.5)
                cout << "* ";
            else
                cout << "  ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

}

void drawSpray(Circle *p)
{
    double d = p->getDensity();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int rto = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 80; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 80; i++)
        {
            x = abs(i - 30);
            y = abs(j - 30);
            d = pow(pow(x, rto) + pow(y, rto), 0.5);

            if(19.5 < d && d < 20.5)
                cout << "* ";
            else
                cout << "  ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void deleteAll(Circle *arr[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != nullptr)
            delete arr[i];
    }
}
```

My Current Output:

```
Circle #1001

                       * * * * * * * * *
```

Expected Output: (example)

```
Circle #1001

                        *************
                    **                 **
                 **                       **
               *                             *
             **                               **
            *                                   *
           *                                     *
          *                                       *
          *                                       *
          *                                       *
          *                                       *
          *                                       *
          *                                       *
          *                                       *
           *                                     *
            *                                   *
             **                               **
               *                             *
                 **                       **
                    **                 **
                        *************

Circle #1002

                              ***************
                         ***                   ***
                      **                           **
                    *                                 *
                  *                                     *
                **                                       **
               *                                           *
              *                                             *
             *                                               *
            **                                               **
            *                                                 *
            *                                                 *
            *                                                 *
            *                                                 *
            *                                                 *
            *                                                 *
            **                                               **
             *                                               *
              *                                             *
               *                                           *
                **                                       **
                  *                                     *
                    *                                 *
                      **                           **
                         ***                   ***
                              ***************

Circle #1003

                                                    *****************                                                   
                                             ***                         ***                                            
                                         **                                   **                                        
                                      *                                           *                                     
                                   **                                               **                                  
                                 *                                                     *                                
                               *                                                         *                              
                             *                                                             *                            
                           **                                                               **                          
                          *                                                                   *                         
                         *                                                                     *                        
                        *                                                                       *                       
                       *                                                                         *                      
                      *                                                                           *                     
                     *                                                                             *                    
                     *                                                                             *                    
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                    *                                                                               *                   
                     *                                                                             *                    
                     *                                                                             *                    
                      *                                                                           *                     
                       *                                                                         *                      
                        *                                                                       *                       
                         *                                                                     *                        
                          *                                                                   *                         
                           **                                                               **                          
                             *                                                             *                            
                               *                                                         *                              
                                 *                                                     *                                
                                   **                                               **                                  
                                      *                                           *                                     
                                         **                                   **                                        
                                             ***                         ***                                            
                                                    *****************
```

Comment: When you find the exact line in your program that writes `std::endl` at the end of each line, you should be able to figure out your own bug.

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j <= 40; i++)`? Did you notice which counter you increment in this loop?

Comment: It's unrelated but is there a reason you use an array of pointer and dynamic memory allocation? `Circle arrCircle[SIZE] = {Circle('C', 1001, 20), Circle('S', 1002, 25, 30), Circle('S', 1003, 40, 80)};` would also work, your objects are on the stack and don't need to delete them.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple algorithm it may be helpful with simple mathematics

```
#include <iostream>
```

#include <graphics.h>

int main() {

```
initgraph();
setcolorRGB(23, 143, 44);
int j = 400;
int r = 50; // this is the radius
for (int i = 200;i < 800;i++) {
    for (int j = 200;j < 800;j++) {
        int p = int(sqrt((pow(i-350,2))+(pow(j-350,2)))); // this is the distance between two points
        if (r == p) {
            putpixel(j,i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this really answers the question? Please provide the output as well, so that we know it answers the question asked by OP.